# Anchor tag href and onclick

Tags: javascript, chm, html-help-workshop

I am very new to JavaScript and i am using JavaScript in **HTML help workshop** to produce compiled help files in chm format.here i need anchor tag to link one html page and also to highlight the user searched word in that page.

So, anchor tag has to do both **href**(for link as a variable) and **onclick**(for highlight word) functionalities.(execute href first then onclick function as second).i tried a lot.but all are failure.

help me to solve this problem and  please use the following **innerHTML** way...

```
<script>

..........
..........

frameDoc.body.innerHTML='<div><br><ul>';

for( l = 0; l < k; l++ )
{
     var tmp1=searched_headings_filename[l];
     var tmp2=searched_headings[l];
     frameDoc.body.innerHTML+='<div style="margin-left:10;"><li class="highlight"><a href="'+tmp1+'" onclick="highlightSearch();">'+searched_headings[l]+'</a></li></div>';
}

frameDoc.body.innerHTML+='</ul></div>';

..........
.......... 

</script>


<script>

function highlightSearch() 
{
     alert('Successfully highlighted');
}

</script>
```

Comment: you want to add a click event on the class highlight right?

Comment: why must it be done with the slow innerHTML way?

Comment: what is frameDoc.body ? its an selector of your body ? aNd in for loop you are using K it is wrong where is k ? and  in for loop use k.length if it is array

Comment: Dear jameshwart lopez, i want to add onclick event for anchor tag which has 'tmp1' as a href. and i used highlight class for just style purpose...

Comment: Dear jameshwart lopez, i want to add onclick event for anchor tag which has 'tmp1' as a href. and i used highlight class for just style purpose...like...<style type="text/css">

.highlight a
{
  font-family:cambria;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:rgb(0,187,254);
  text-decoration:none;
}

.highlight a:active
{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

.highlight a:hover
{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

Comment: Dear Jaromanda X, i did some script by using innerHTMl in my coding. so i prefer innerHTML is there any other easy way?...Please tell me...

Comment: Dear Keval Bhatt, 
    var frame = top.window.document.getElementById ("Homepage_TOC_ID");

var frameDoc = frame.contentWindow.document;

frameDoc.body.innerHTML='<div><br><ul>';             and k is a variable and i find it before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quit sure but it seems to me there is another way to solve the problem you described. So, I'll post some hints to highlight words in searched topics. This may be a solution for you combined with a normal HTML anchor link. A German CHM viewer window has a tab *Suchen*  (Search) on the left side navigation pane.

When searching for words in Help topics, you can specify that each occurrence of the word or phrase you searched for is highlighted in the topics that are found.

- On the Viewer toolbar, click View and then click Highlights to add a 
  checkmark to this option to highlight all instances of the word or
  phrase.
- On the Viewer toolbar, click View and then click Highlights    to
  remove    the checkmark from this option and to turn off this
  feature.

For special case (see snapshots) there are some methods using JavaScript. You may download the sample files from:
http://www.help-info.de/files_download/CHM-example_project.zip
Please note: To open this ZIP / CHM file right-click the saved file (ZIP before extracting) , click Properties, and then click Unblock.

For some further search information please have a look at:
http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_fts.htm

[image]
[image]